Number of object in the S3 bucket drops after the deployment of expiration rules, and then rises back at the same number one day after
Hi community I hope you can help me with a beginner question.  
We are deploying a change of our cloud formation template for a S3 bucket  We are deploying these lifecycle rules  
LifecycleConfiguration:
  Rules:
    - Id: ExpireOldFiles
      Status: Enabled
      ExpirationInDays: 435 
      NoncurrentVersionExpiration:
        NoncurrentDays: 30

We see that after deploying the changes the number of object in the S3 bucket drops, and then is back at the same number one day after. We do not know how to explain this behaviour. Would you have some suggestions for how to explain this behaviour, or in which direction to look for clues? 
We understand that metrics are delivered on a best-effort basis, and there may be some things that are missing to the metric, while the actual number of the bucket object is not changing.
S3 bucket metric documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html
[metric screenshot]
[metric screenshot]
What did we actually expect?￼
We were expecting the number of object to drop after deployment, and remain the same until new files were added.
After reading and contextualizing further the documentation, I begun thinking that since the S3 bucket apply the delete marker to the asset instead of removing it completely, we would expect the number of objects to remain the same throughout, instead we see this V shaped graph.
Thank you in advance for time and your help!
